# Change in the order of hooks error from context to useEffect

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

ERROR  Warning: React has detected a change in the order of Hooks called by AuthPage. This will lead to bugs and errors if not fixed. For more information, read the Rules of Hooks: https://reactjs.org/link/rules-of-hooks

| Previous render | Next Render |
| --- | --- |
| useContext | useContext |
| useContext | useContext |
| useState | useState |
| useEffect | useEffect |
| useContext | useEffect |

The code:

```
import React, { useContext, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { Keyboard } from 'react-native';
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { getCredentials } from '../util/Storage';
import { OrderContext } from '../OrderContext';
import { UserContext } from '../UserContext';

const AuthPage = ({ navigation }) => {
  const userContext = useContext(UserContext);
  const orderContext = useContext(OrderContext);
  const [isKeyboardVisible, setKeyboardVisibile] = useState(false);
  useEffect(() => {
    const getCreds = async () => {
      const c = await getCredentials();
      if (c) {
        navigation.replace('Home' : 'StartWizard');
      }
    };
    getCreds();
  }, []);

  const keyboardDidShow = () => {
    setKeyboardVisibile(true);
  };

  const keyboardDidHide = () => {
    setKeyboardVisibile(false);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    Keyboard.addListener('keyboardDidShow', keyboardDidShow);
    Keyboard.addListener('keyboardDidHide', keyboardDidHide);

    return () => {
      Keyboard.removeListener('keyboardDidShow', keyboardDidShow);
      Keyboard.removeListener('keyboardDidHide', keyboardDidHide);
    };
  }, []);

  if (!global.navigation) {
    global.navigation = useNavigation();
  }

  return (
    <AuthView ... />
      }}
    />
  );
};

const Auth = ({ navigation }) => <AuthPage navigation={navigation} />;
export default Auth;
```

Why is the order changing and how do I correct this behavior?

Comment: Possibly you are using your hooks in an if or a loop. Could you post the code that is causing this error?

Comment: @AdamJeliński Added my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

React always expects the same hooks to be called, no matter what values your variables have.

In this case, you conditionally call the `useNavigation()` hook, which completely messes up what React wants.

To fix it, just store the value returned by the hook in a temporary variable:

```
const currentNavigation = useNavigation();
if (!global.navigation) {
    global.navigation = currentNavigation;
}
```

or overwrite the `global.navigation` unconditionally if it's not a problem

```
global.navigation = useNavigation();
```

I strongly recommend reading up on the [rules of hooks](https://reactjs.org/link/rules-of-hooks), so you can avoid errors like this in the future.

Answer (score 0):

```
  if (!global.navigation) {
    global.navigation = useNavigation();
  }
```

Never conditionally call a hook. [Its a rule of hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#only-call-hooks-at-the-top-level)